# Array merge depends on array key

Tags: php, arrays

How can I merge the array with the same key(using date as a key) but different values? I used to create a code but the problem is the value that stores is only one per key but they have a same key(date).

Here's my array:

```
          {
                posting_date: "2017-08-08 00:00:00",
                id: 1,
                title: "activity 1",
                category: "company_news"
          },
          {
                posting_date: "2017-08-08 00:00:00",
                id: 6,
                title: "testing",
                category: "building_process_update"
          },
          {
                posting_date: "2017-08-08 00:00:00",
                id: 7,
                title: "ttest1",
                category: "company_news"
          },
```

Here's my code:

```
    foreach ($result_post as $key => $value){
        $year = date('Y',strtotime($value['posting_date']));
        $month = date('M',strtotime($value['posting_date']));
        $day = date('d',strtotime($value['posting_date']));
        // $result[$year] = $value['posting_date'];
        $data = [$value['title']];
        $side_bar_date[$value['category']][$year][$month][$day] = ['id'=>$value['id'],'title'=>$value['title']];

    }
```

but the output is

```
   building_process_update: {
             2017: {
                 Aug: {
                    08: {
                       id: 6,
                       title: "testing"
                    }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: I've already edit the exact output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `overwriting` the `day` key `consequently`. you need to push the value  into `day` key as `array` `[]` like below

```
$side_bar_date[$value['category']][$year][$month][$day][] = ['id'=>$value['id'],'title'=>$value['title']];
```

Comment: Glad it help you @clien

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
foreach ($result_post as $key => $value){
        $year = date('Y',strtotime($value['posting_date']));
        $month = date('M',strtotime($value['posting_date']));
        $day = date('d',strtotime($value['posting_date']));
        // $result[$year] = $value['posting_date'];
        $data = [$value['title']];
        $side_bar_date[$value['category']][$year][$month][$day][] = array('id'=>$value['id'],'title'=>$value['title']);
    }
```

This is working in my case.